# Java - Status 401 - PAC Proxy authentication for JSoup

Tags: java, proxy, jsoup, pac

I'm trying to use Jsoup to gather elements from a webpage, however I am behind a PAC Proxy.  When I try to access a website using Jsoup I get a code status 401 Authentication error. It seems issue is with proxy. I have installed a library called Proxy-Vole that should authenticate me but I believe I am not using it right. What I wish is to ultimately authenticate against the proxy and continue however way possible.

```
ProxySearch proxySearch = new ProxySearch();
if (PlatformUtil.getCurrentPlattform() == Platform.WIN) {
    proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.IE);
    proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.FIREFOX);
    proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.JAVA);
} else if (PlatformUtil.getCurrentPlattform() == Platform.LINUX) {
    proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.GNOME);
    proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.KDE);
    proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.FIREFOX);
} else {
    proxySearch.addStrategy(Strategy.OS_DEFAULT);
}

ProxySelector proxySelector = proxySearch.getProxySelector();
ProxySelector.setDefault(proxySelector);

Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.whatever.com").get();
```

Answer (score 1):

As the [guide](https://github.com/MarkusBernhardt/proxy-vole#choose-the-right-proxy) explains you should select the right proxy for your request. I updated the changed the example code for this a bit with Java Streams:

```
URI uri = new URI("https://www.whatever.com");

Proxy proxy = Optional.ofNullable(ProxySelector.getDefault())
        .map(ps -> ps.select(uri))
        .stream().flatMap(List::stream)
        .max(Comparator.comparing(Proxy::type))
        .orElse(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
```

This example uses the proxies by the following priority: `SOCKS`, `HTTP`, `DIRECT`. You can easily change that by wrapping it in a separate method:

```
private static int getPriority(Proxy.Type type) {
    switch (type) {
        case HTTP:
            return 2;
        case SOCKS:
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Use this with `Comparator.comparingInt(p -> getPriority(p.type()))` in `.max()`. Alternatively you can use the official example code which I linked above.

You now can use that `proxy` in your Jsoup connection:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(uri.toString())
        .proxy(proxy)
        .get();
```

Beside that you should make sure that your connection is working through the proxy. If your proxy requires authentication follow [this part](https://github.com/MarkusBernhardt/proxy-vole#how-to-handle-proxy-authentication) of the guide. For troubleshooting you can use the [Proxy Vole Tester](https://github.com/MarkusBernhardt/proxy-vole#proxy-vole-tester).